# After Lion installation, Safari occasional unresponsive, won't take input

Tags: macos, safari, imac

Since installing Lion, I've had Safari 5.1 become unresponsive to input several times on two different machines (both iMacs, in different locations).

I don't see anything in the forums I quickly checked. Any ideas?

(Safari becomes responsive again after quitting and restarting. Input device -- mouse, trackpad -- makes no difference.)

Comment: This problem effects newer Macs as well. I have a brand new MacBook Pro and experience random text input freezes when using safari. MacBook Pro 8,2
Safari 5.1.2,
OS X 10.7.2,
8 gb RAM,
2.5 gHz i7,

Answer (score 3):

Try completely clearing out Safari of junk.

First, empty the cache by hitting ***Safari > Empty Cache...***.

[image: empty cache]

Click ***Empty***.

[image: are you sure]

Then completely reset Safari by hitting ***Safari > Reset Safari***.

[image: reset]

Check all the checks and hit ***Reset***.

[image: sure reset]

Then quit and relaunch Safari. That should speed things up.

If not, you can always use another browser. ^cough^Chrome^cough^

Answer (score 0):

Has nothing to do with resetting anything or emptying any cache. Ignorance of mouse clicks is a Mac OS X 10.7 bug which seems to occur on older Macs and should be addressed by Apple.

Comment: Might you have a radar number to track this bug?